# Additive bounds animation only works when target value is smaller.

Tags: swift3, core-animation

I'm trying to animate the bounds using an additive technique. (Where the animation goes to 0 and starts at a negative difference). It works when animating to a *smaller* bounds but breaks for a *larger* bounds. When animating to a larger bounds, it snaps to the final bounds value + the inverse of the target bounds value. e.g. If we animate from 100x100 to 200x200, the animation snaps to 300x300 and animates to 200x200. It looks like the target value with negative width and height is being standardized somewhere under the hood. (e.g. -100x-100 becomes 100x100) I'm not sure how to get around this though.

Code in a touchesBegan handler. myLayer is 100x100

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue: http://www.openradar.me/12085417

The workaround is to animate `"bounds.size"`. But you also need to set the model layer's `bounds` directly opposed to using `setValue(targetValue, forKey: "bounds.size")`.

Comment: This bug is still happening as of 10.14.6 / 10.15.3